# Creating kit for building 32 bit application

Tags: c++, qt

I need to build 32 bit application with QT that will run in Linux. I suppose for this reason I should manage kit for building 32 bit binary. Current only one kit I have builds 64 bit ones.

[image]

What should be changed in this kit in order to compile 32 bit application?

Attempt 1

I was trying to run QT install once again in order to install QT Maintainency 
 Tool. I expect I will add kit with help of it. I found that installer is planning to install QT indirectory I don't have `/home/g/Qt`. I afraid to get mess of two QT installs in my PC

Attempt 2

Install 32 bit libs also gived nothing:

sudo aptitude install glibc-devel.i386 libstdc++-devel.i386 qt5-qtbase-devel.i386

Output:

```
Couldn't find any package whose name or description matched "glibc-devel.i386"
Couldn't find any package whose name or description matched "libstdc++-devel.i386"
Couldn't find any package whose name or description matched "qt5-qtbase-devel.i386"
Couldn't find any package whose name or description matched "glibc-devel.i386"
Couldn't find any package whose name or description matched "libstdc++-devel.i386"
Couldn't find any package whose name or description matched "qt5-qtbase-devel.i386"
No packages will be installed, upgraded, or removed.
0 packages upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 7 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B of archives. After unpacking 0 B will be used.
```

Comment: Launch the Qt Maintenance Tool and select *"Add or remove components"*, then add a 32-bit kit.

Comment: Where is located Qt Maintenance Tool? Should i install it?

Comment: You have Qt Maintenance Tool when you install Qt from the [online installer](https://www.qt.io/download-qt-installer?hsCtaTracking=9f6a2170-a938-42df-a8e2-a9f0b1d6cdce%7C6cb0de4f-9bb5-4778-ab02-bfb62735f3e5)

Answer (score 1):

You need to first install 32 bit system & Qt libraries. For centos/redhat, thats something like

```
yum -y install glibc-devel.i386 libstdc++-devel.i386 qt5-qtbase-devel.i386
```

Other systems should be similar.

Then just set Qt mkspec to `linux-g++-32` in the kit

Comment: Looks like Ubuntu not finds `sudo aptitude install glibc-devel.i386 libstdc++-devel.i386 qt5-qtbase-devel.i386
[sudo] password for g: 
Couldn't find any package whose name or description matched "glibc-devel.i386"
Couldn't find any package whose name or description matched "libstdc++-devel.i386"
Couldn't find any package whose name or description matched "qt5-qtbase-devel.i386"
Couldn't find any package whose name or description matched "glibc-devel.i386"
Couldn't find any package whose name or description matched "libstdc++-devel.i386"
`

Comment: Don't use ubuntu, but I think you need package `qtbase5-dev:i386`

Comment: I don't use ubuntu*